# ggplot fill variable to add to 100%

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a dataframe

```
DF <- data.frame(SchoolYear = c("2015-2016", "2016-2017"), 
                 Value = sample(c('Agree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly agree', 'Strongly disagree'), 50, replace = TRUE))
```

I have created this graph.

```
ggplot(DF, aes(x = Value, fill = SchoolYear)) +
       geom_bar(position = 'dodge', aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) +   
       geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), 
                 stat = "count", vjust = -0.25, size = 2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
       scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
       ylab("Percent") + xlab("Response") +   
       theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

Is there a way to make the data for each school year add up to 100%, but not have the data stacked, in the graph?

I know this question is similar to this question [Create stacked barplot where each stack is scaled to sum to 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563368/create-stacked-barplot-where-each-stack-is-scaled-to-sum-to-100), but I don't want the graph to be stacked. I can't figure out how to apply the solution in my question to this situation. Also I would prefer not to summarize the data before graphing, as I have to make this graph many times using different data each time and would prefer not to have to summarize the data each time.

Comment: You can summarize your data prior to plotting, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776200/ggplot-replace-count-with-percentage-in-geom-bar)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ggplot replace count with percentage in geom\_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776200/ggplot-replace-count-with-percentage-in-geom-bar)

Comment: @MikeH. is there a way to do it without summarising my data before hand?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to create the plot that you want without transforming the data. But if you want to re-use the same code for multiple datasets, you can write a function to transform your data and generate the plot at the same time:

```
plot.fun <- function (original.data) {
    newDF <- reshape2::melt(apply(table(original.data), 1, prop.table))
    Plot <- ggplot(newDF, aes(x=Value, y=value)) + 
            geom_bar(aes(fill=SchoolYear), stat="identity", position="dodge") +
            geom_text(aes(group=SchoolYear, label=scales::percent(value)), stat="identity", vjust=-0.25, size=2, position=position_dodge(width=0.85)) + 
            scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) + 
            ylab("Percent") + xlab("Response") +   
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1))
    return (Plot)
}
plot.fun(DF)
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

**Big Disclaimer:** I would *highly* recommend you summarize your data before hand and not try to do these calculations within `ggplot`. That is not what `ggplot` is meant to do. Furthermore, it not only complicates your code unnecessarily, but can easily introduce bugs/unintended results.

Given that, it appears that what you want is doable (without summarizing first). A very hacky way to get what you want by doing the calculations within ggplot would be:

```
#Store factor values
fac <- unique(DF$SchoolYear)

ggplot(DF, aes(x = Value, fill = SchoolYear)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', aes(y = (..count..)/stats::ave(..count.., get("fac", globalenv()), FUN = sum))) +   
  geom_text(aes(y = (..count..)/stats::ave(..count.., get("fac", globalenv()), FUN = sum), label = scales::percent((..count..)/stats::ave(..count.., get("fac", globalenv()), FUN = sum))),
            stat = "count", vjust = -0.25, size = 2, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  ylab("Percent") + xlab("Response") +   
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 75, hjust = 1))
```

[image]

This takes the `..count..` variable and divides it by the sum within it's respective group using `stats::ave`. Note this can be messed up *extremely* easily.

Finally, we check to see the plot is in fact giving us what we want.

```
#Check to see we have the correct values
d2 <- DF
d2 <- setDT(d2)[, .(count = .N), by = .(SchoolYear, Value)][, percent := count/sum(count), by = SchoolYear]
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice and the suggestion. I appreciate the help!