# Use count in the y-axis but percentages and counts as labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I am trying to create a bar chart in R from a data frame, which has counts in the y-axis but displays as labels a concatenation of percentages and counts.

My data frame looks as below:

```
ID    Response
1    No
2    Yes
3    No
..    ..
```

The end result I would like to have would be a chart as the one below

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I have tried creating a cross tab with the counts and the frequencies - as below:   U1 <- train %>% 
group_by(Survived) %>% 
summarise(count = n()) %>% 
mutate(perc = count/sum(count))  and then used ggplot2 to plot it - or at least i tried it

Comment: Add your code attempt to your question.

Comment: Sorry OTStats - I edited my previous answer

Comment: I have also seen that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776200/ggplot-replace-count-with-percentage-in-geom-bar/24777521 which gives a close solution but I can't seem to configure the ggplot to achieve my purpose

Comment: The example that you have provided doesn't make any sense. How can the counts for both Yes and No be 320 but there are different percentages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(Response) %>%
  summarise(count = n()) %>%
  mutate(Label = paste0(count, " - ", round(count / sum(count) * 100, 2), "%")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Response, y = count)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', fill = 'lightblue') +
  geom_text(aes(label = Label)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

A solution as above can be to create a `Label` column which you can then pass to `geom_text` if needed.

A dummy data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1:100),
  Response = c(rep("Yes", 60), rep("No", 40))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd try something like the below. It's awesome that you're using `summarize` and `mutate`; I guess by habit I sometimes use base functions like `table`.

```
library(tidyverse)
resps<-sample(c("yes", "no"), 850, replace=T)

percents<-round(100*table(resps)/length(resps),2)
counts<-as.numeric(table(resps))

plotdat<-data.frame(percents, counts=counts, response=rownames(percents))


plotdat %>% ggplot(aes(response, counts)) +
    geom_col()+
    geom_text(aes(y=counts+10), label=paste(percents,"%  ", counts))
    labs(y="respondents")+
    theme_classic()
```

Comment: Thank you- that is also exactly the solution |I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is a helpful solution from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695497/show-instead-of-counts-in-charts-of-categorical-variables) on SO:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
data.frame(response = sample(c("Yes", "No"), size = 100, replace = T, prob = c(0.4, 0.6))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = response)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..))) + 
  geom_text(aes(y = ((..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
            label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..))), stat = "count", vjust = -0.25) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) + 
  labs(title = "Proportion of Responses", y = "Percent", x = "Response")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response OTStats - unfortunately it does not answer my question as it does not display counts and percentages, but thank you for the effort