# How to use stat="count" to label a bar chart with counts or percentages in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I'm trying to produce a stacked column chart with data labels.

I'm able to produce the chart, but was unable to find a way to input data labels. I have tried `geom_text()` but it keeps asking me to input a y label (which if you see the ggplot code is not there). I have also tried adding `geom_text(stat = "count")` but that also gives me an error saying

> "Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: y and label".

PS - i'm aware I need to rename the y axis as percentage. I'm also trying to figure out how to have more contrasting colours

```
ggplot(property,
       aes(x=Bedrooms.New, fill=Property.Type.)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "fill") + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Number of Bedrooms", 
                   limits = sort(factor(unique(property$Bedrooms.New))))
```

I have added an image below to see what my output is right now!

[image]

Comment: What kind of data labels are you trying to produce? Category label? Number of observations? Proportion of observations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the error message is telling you, `geom_text` requires the `label` aes. In your case you want to label the bars with a variable which is not part of your dataset but instead computed by `stat="count"`, i.e. `stat_count`.

The computed variable can be accessed via `..NAME_OF_COMPUTED_VARIABLE..`. , e.g. to get the counts use `..count..` as variable name. BTW: A list of the computed variables can be found on the help package of the stat or geom, e.g. `?stat_count`

**UPDATE: The dot-dot notation was deprecated in `ggplot2 3.4.0`. Instead we could or should use `after_stat`, i.e. use e.g. `after_stat(count)` instead of `..count..`**

Using `mtcars` as an example dataset you can label a `geom_bar` like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = after_stat(count)),
    stat = "count", position = "fill"
  )
```

[image]

Two more notes:

1. To get the position of the labels right you have to set the `position` argument to match the one used in `geom_bar`, e.g. `position="fill"` in your case.
2. While counts are pretty easy, labelling with percentages is a different issue. By default `stat_count` computes percentages by group, e.g. by the groups set via the `fill` aes. These can be accessed via `after_stat(prop)`. If you want the percentages to be computed differently, you have to do it manually.

As an example if you want the percentages to sum to 100% per bar this could be achieved using `after_stat` and `ave` (to compute the percentage per group) like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, fill = factor(gear))) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(
    aes(label = after_stat(
      scales::percent(
        ave(count, x, FUN = function(x) x / sum(x))
      )
    )),
    stat = "count", position = "fill"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I've been looking for this comment all day! a way to calculate percentages without modifying the dataframe! THANK YOU!

Comment: This answer (which I love because it worked for me too!) illustrates exactly why I was NEVER going to be able to figure out on my own how to simply add percents to my stacked barchart without doing the dplyr summarising work myself before the ggplot code.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a follow-up to the answer above, since this answer usually gets me 90% of the way, but I can never remember how to also:

- center the labels (`position_fill(vjust = 0.5)`)
- make the percent labels pretty (`scales::percent()`)

```r
library(ggplot)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, fill = factor(gear)))+
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(..count.. / tapply(..count.., ..x.., sum)[as.character(..x..)])), stat = "count", position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

And here's an alternative with pre-calculations in advance:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  count(gear, cyl) %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(cyl, perc, fill = factor(gear)))+
  geom_col(position = "fill") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(perc)), position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5))
```