# Change geom_bar to percentages instead of count

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, geom-bar

I'm making an interactive time series with Bar graphs using ggplot and after that converting it to plotly. Each bar represents one year 16,17 and 18 (data_long.edad) and I color them according to ocupation (data_long.ocup).
My graph is showing **count** but I would like to be able to show the **percentages for each bar** (each bar should add up to 100%)
I have tried many methods and failed.
My problem is VERY similar to this question [ggplot replace count with percentage in geom_bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24776200/ggplot-replace-count-with-percentage-in-geom-bar/48602277)  but I cant make that solution work. I can´t transform my data (maybe because in my case I have factor variables?).

Any ideas?

```
>   head(df,20)
    data_long.edad         data_long.ocup
1             a16r        Oc. de limpieza
2             a18r         Aún no ingesa al ML
3             a18r       Aún no ingesa al ML
4             a17r   Aún no ingesa al ML
5             a17r   Aún no ingesa al ML
6             a16r  Oficiales y operarios
7             a17r   Aún no ingesa al ML
8             a17r   Aún no ingesa al ML
9             a17r   Trab. de los servicios
10            a16r    Aún no ingesa al ML
11            a16r Trab. de los servicios
12            a16r    Aún no ingesa al ML
13            a18r       Administrativos
14            a18r       Oficiales y operarios
15            a16r      Trab. calificados
16            a18r       Aún no ingesa al ML
17            a18r       Aún no ingesa al ML
18            a18r       Aún no ingesa al ML
19            a16r  Oficiales y operarios
20            a16r    Aún no ingesa al ML




  gocup <-  ggplot(df, aes(x=data_long.edad)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=factor(data_long.ocup))) +
    ggtitle("Trayectorias ocupacionales") 
  
  gocup
  
  rm (ocuint)
  ocupint = ggplotly(p= gocup, tooltip= c("x", "y")) %>%
    style(hoverlabel = labels) %>%
    layout(font = TRUE,
           yaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE),
           showlegend = TRUE,
           legend=list(title=list(text='<b> Ocupación </b>')),
           xaxis = list(fixedrange = TRUE)) %>%
    config(displayModeBar = FALSE)
  
  ocupint
```

My graph looks like this, instead of count I would like percentage and each bar goes up to 100.
(This graphs shows more years and more occupations than the data example I provided, but the same data structure)
[image: Plot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `position = "fill"` in the `geom_bar()` call. This fills everything up to 100%:

```r
# From some random data
tibble(a = sample(letters[1:10], 5000, replace = TRUE),
       b = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 5000, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(a, fill = b)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "percent",
                     breaks = c(0, 0.5, 1), 
                     labels = scales::percent(c(0, 0.5, 1)))
```

This uses some of the notation from the other solution to do percentages:

[image]

Comment: Andrew is correct. You can also include name="Percent" in the scale_y_continuous function to change the work "count" to "Percent".

Comment: well spotted - lazy me!